# Simple web service solution for iOS and ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

The architecture which iPhone works as client, communicating with back-end service by RESTful way,Ruby on Rails is good at building REST web service.

So just wonder if there is very simple open source project for this sort of solution available now ?  ( Just like hello world.)

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking in to this as well. The closest thing to a fully integrated solution on the Objective-C side I've seen is [ObjectiveResource](http://iphoneonrails.com/) but it doesn't look very well maintained anymore.

Comment: it's not very well maintained

Comment: Actually in terms of client part, I prefer ASIHttpRequest. RESTful service is based on HTTP usually. Here I wanna know more about server part with ruby. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Check out [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) if you're looking to build an API using rails. It would be a good server complement to RestKit on the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) for object mapping.

Comment: Any existed free web server for restkit to use ?

Comment: You can use Rails app on your web server, or use some commercial (heroku for example). There is one more, new web service for server side stuff for iOS developer, called Parse. It's in beta, but you can try it, it's free now: https://www.parse.com/